# Как запустить вторую консоль при другом потоке?

Tags: c++

У меня есть два потока, я бы хотел открывать новую консоль, если открылся другой поток, как это сделать?

Comment: В стандартной библиотеке такого нет. Только платформо-зависимый код. На счёт линукса не знаю, но в Windows есть `AllocConsole`.

Comment: @MrBin Это почему то, не работает для меня.

Comment: @DarthVader Что значит "не работает"? Мы же не телепаты.

Comment: AllocConsole(); ничего не делает

Comment: @MrBin Почитал [мануал](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/allocconsole) - написано, что `AllocConsole` не позволяет иметь больше одной консоли на процесс.

Comment: Попробуйте перенаправлять stderr и stdout в новую сессию bash

Comment: @Beeen007 ТС, похоже, на Винде.

Comment: Потому что ни один процесс не может иметь более одной консоли (В мануале про `AllocConsole` это написано). В таком случае просто создаю дочерний процесс со своей консолью и перенаправляют stdin, stdout и stderr в родительский процесс. В вашем случае на один новый поток будет приходиться по 1 новому набору вышеперечисленных потоков.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, там написано про ограничение количества прикрепленных окно, но никто не запрещает создать дочерним процессам новые окна таким способом:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если необходимо многооконная текстовая индикация, можно делать эмуляцию своей собственной консоли, создавая окна для вывода текста и реализуя основной функционал самостоятельно. Так деалают AutoCAD, Visual Studio. Нативная консоль может быть только одна.
Если нужно точное воспроизведение консолей, в таком создаются дочерний процессы со своей консолью и данные им передаются черец  конвейеры (pipes).
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/190351/EN-US

MS Visual Studio делает и обратное - перенаправляет вывод дочерних процессов к себе и выводит результаты в окне Output.